# C# TableLayout doubling in height when adding rows?

Tags: c#, tablelayout

I have a tableLayout that I am adding a row to each time I click a button.

But when I add the row that cannot fit into the tableLayout it expands horizontally which is fine.
However each time it 'expands' (When the scrollbar fills to max) it expands to twice the size, not just 1 rows worth of height.

I focus on the 5th row so the user will have 5 on screen and 5 free on top if the table can only show 5 at a time.
Then they can just scroll down to see all the old ones as the rows are added from bottom up.

Any idea?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     
            Addlabel("message", "response");
        }


        private void Addlabel(String message, string response)
        {

            Label messageLbl = new Label();
            messageLbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            messageLbl.Text = message;
            messageLbl.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 12.0F); 

            Label responseLbl = new Label();
            responseLbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            responseLbl.Text = response;
            responseLbl.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 12.0F); 

            messageLbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            messageLbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            responseLbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            responseLbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(messageLbl, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(responseLbl, 1, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);

            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;

            tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 5;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the height of the row you're adding i.e:

```
 tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle (System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
```

Note: Absolute means the height of of the row is fixed size, other wise you use Percent which will allow it to expand.